# pyspark.errors.exceptions.captured.IllegalArgumentException: Output column features already exists

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

This is my code below and I am getting this error "pyspark.errors.exceptions.captured.IllegalArgumentException: Output column features already exists" i checked other posts but I am not sure what needs to be done can anyone please help here.

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.ml.feature import StringIndexer, VectorAssembler
from pyspark.ml.classification import LinearSVC
from pyspark.ml import Pipeline
from pyspark.ml.evaluation import MulticlassClassificationEvaluator

# Create a SparkSession
spark = SparkSession.builder.appName("").getOrCreate()

# Load your TSV file into a DataFrame
data = spark.read.csv("sleep.tsv", sep='\t', header=True, inferSchema=True)

input_cols = ["V0", "V1", "V2", "V3", "V4", "V5", "V6", "V7", "V8", "V9", "V10", "V11", "V12"]

# Concatenate input columns into a single column named "features"
assembler = VectorAssembler(inputCols=input_cols, outputCol= "features")
data_assembled = assembler.transform(data)

# Renamed target column to label
data_assembled = data_assembled.withColumnRenamed("target", "label")

### Split data into training and testing sets
(trainingData, testData) = new_data.randomSplit([0.8, 0.2], seed=16)

### Fit the pipeline to training data
model = pipeline.fit(trainingData)
```